# Copy 2D array using memcpy

Tags: c

I wanna use memcpy but its usually define as a pointer. can we assign a new memory to an array with this function?

for example we have a `matrix1[13][15]` and we want to assign it to `matrix2[13][15]` while these two arrays are independent.

Comment: more generally, it's important to know the differences between pointers and arrays and how they are related: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Also there is a thing that you might want to notice - it doesn't matter if it is like this

```
int *p =&matrix1[0][0];
int *q =&matrix2[0][0];
memcpy(p, q, 13*15*sizeof(*p));
```

Sure you can do this also,

```
memcpy(&matrix2[0][0], &matrix1[0][0], 13*15*sizeof(matrix1[0][0]));
```

---

```
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1,
             const void * restrict s2,
             size_t n);
```

Why this works? Because `memcpy` function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the object pointed to by `s1`. Well this basically sums up every thing you need to use `memcpy`. So what happens if it is a pointer - the strategy will be same. Pointer point to source and target and they don't overlap - and you then mention the bytes. Voila - it would copy.

Another thing to note - you can get these values `13` and `15` using sizeof operator.

```
size_t rows = sizeof matrix1 / sizeof matrix1[0];
size_t cols = sizeof matrix1[0] / sizeof matrix1[0][0];

memcpy(&matrix2[0][0], &matrix1[0][0], rows*cols*sizeof(matrix1[0][0]));
```

And also even more clearly (lurker suggested) :-

```
memcpy(&matrix2[0][0], &matrix1[0][0], sizeof matrix1);
```

And these would also work (It was chux who mentioned this)

```
memcpy(matrix2, matrix1, sizeof matrix2);
```

Because they all have same value - pointing to same address but their type is different which anyway doesn't matter here because it is converted to `void*`.

---

An even better solution which would work whether these variables denotes array or struct or some scalar variable is (suggested by chux )

```
memcpy(&matrix2, &matrix1, sizeof matrix2);
```

Comment: The OP never mentioned the type of the array. So you'd have `sizeof(<type of array element>)`. Might even be able to just use `sizeof(matrix1)` instead of `13*15*sizeof(...)` if the dimensions are constant.

Comment: @lurker.: Yes that would work too.

Comment: @lurker.: For VLA's also it would work though. sizeof of VLA is expression.

Comment: Ok, cool! I wasn't absolutely sure...

Comment: Surprised you did not suggest `memcpy(matrix2, matrix1, sizeof matrix2);`

Comment: @chux.:Ah yes..because ultimetly it boils down to `void*`..then I should also suggest `memcpy(matrix2[0], matrix1[0], sizeof matrix2);`

Comment: @chux.: Check the edit and thanks. Let me know if I misssed something

Comment: Why [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions) `memcpy(matrix2[0], matrix1[0], sizeof matrix2);` vs. the drier `memcpy(matrix2, matrix1, sizeof matrix2);`?

Comment: @chux.: True but there is a small thing that I wanted to show - here `maxtrix[0]` and `matrix` will have different type but there value matters. If you suggest I can edit.

Comment: If anything, I could see `memcpy(&matrix2, &matrix1, sizeof matrix2);` as that works regardless of the type of  `matrix1/matrix2`: array, `struct` or scalar.

Comment: @chux.: haha..yes true.  I will edit it as it is. It's funny how I was avoiding this :)

Comment: @chux.: Well now a days when I answer I concentrate a particukar detail so much that I forget other beautiful ideas. Here I was so concern with proving that the type is not being an issue - well ..thanks a lot.